# Как сделать круглый progresView загрузки файла?

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar

Использую этот код, чтобы скачать файл.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Chapter1.mp3"];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];

if (!fileExists) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSString *stringURL = @"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_mHRsv5WQu6d3plcTlHV2VmaGg";
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

        if (!fileExists) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"detailSegue" sender: self];
        }
    });
}
```

Нужна круглая `progresView` чтобы видеть процесс загрузки файла. Пытался делать, но что-то никак не выходит. Как можно это сделать?

**UPD**

Все работает. Но анимация процесса не видна(`progresView` резко становится синим, когда загрузка завершена)

```
UIProgressView *progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] init];
    progressView.frame = CGRectMake(100,100,100,20);
    [self.view addSubview:progressView];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Chapter1.mp3"];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:false];
    if (!fileExists) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSString *stringURL = @"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B_mHRsv5WQu6Q0V0eEJxSWk0NGg";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

        float progress = [urlData length]/(float)[urlData length];
        [progressView setProgress:progress];
        if (progress == 1.0){

        }
       });
}
```

Comment: а чем `UIActivityIndicatorView` не нравится?

Comment: В нем можно показывать процесс загрузки? Не важно что использовать. Главное чтобы был виден процесс загрузки.

Comment: ааа, вот что надо. на гитхабе посмотрите, там такого много

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут их много, выбирай любой - https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=progress

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: обновляй прогресс в главном потоке:
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [progressView setProgress:progress];
        });